# How to change fontColor when TimePicker is disabled- MUI React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, timepicker

I'm trying to set another color to the text in TimePicker when it is disabled, but with no success. Does anyone knows how to do change it using sx or slotProps? Here is my current code.

```
<TimePicker
          disabled={true} // disabled here
          ampm={false}
          views={['hours', 'minutes', 'seconds']}
          sx={{
            backgroundColor: "#333335",
            font: "white",
            color: "#FFFF",
            textDecoration: "bold",
            input: {
              color: "#FFFF",
              fontSize: "1.4rem",
            }
          }}
          slotProps={{
            popper: {
              sx: {
                "& .MuiList-root": {
                  backgroundColor: "#333335",
                },
                "& .MuiMenuItem-root": {
                  "&.Mui-selected": {
                    backgroundColor: "#04395E",
                    color: "white"
                  },
                  color: "white"
                },
               
              },
            },
          }}
          value={selectedTime}
          onChange={(newTime: any) => setSelectedTime(newTime)}
          timeSteps={{hours: 1, minutes: 1, seconds: 1}}
/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placeholder is styled using the `-webkit-text-fill-color` property. Also, it has an opacity of `.42` by default so any color will be semi-transparent, unless you set the opacity back to `1`:

```
<TimePicker
  sx={{
    input: {
      '&.Mui-disabled': {
        WebkitTextFillColor: '#FFF',
        opacity: 1
      }
    }
  }}
/>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-pasteur-4m8kvs?file=/Demo.tsx).

Comment: Wow, thank you for your answer. But I noticed that it's not pure white, light gray.

Comment: That's because the placeholder has an opacity of `0.42`. I've updated the demo. However, now it no longer looks *"disabled"*.

Comment: Hi @tao! I tried your way by changing the opacity as you explained, but it's not working properly in my example. Here's the codesanbox of the current problem:
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/timepicker-issue-mtzk5x?file=/CustomTimePicker/index.tsx:0-2944)

I made a new post with this problem, I appreciate if you could help me:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76916765/how-to-change-fontcolor-when-disabled-and-change-bordercolor-of-input-when-hover)

Comment: @lucas, sorry, the WebkitTextFillColor needs to be set on the input, not on the placeholder. Updated the answer. As for the border on hover issue, the only way to make it work I found is `'&:hover'.fieldset.borderColor = yourColor + ' !important'`. [Have a look](https://codesandbox.io/s/timepicker-issue-forked-vct56m?file=/CustomTimePicker/index.tsx).